# How to generate p Sample of GGM of dimension m, for parameter : the weight, the means and the covariance?

Tags: linear-algebra, python, statistics, probability, data-sets

after searching in the python numpy, scipy and sklearn module, there is no function who can generate p samples of a gmm (gaussian mixture model) for parameter means, covariances and the weight of each multidimentionnal gaussian of dimension n. Any clue or guidance please to generate that ?
Thank you for your time

Comment: How large is $n$?

Comment: -1. An earlier, now deleted, comment solved this for you, and @stéphanelaurent in, at the moment, an answer below has answered it too without acknowledgement.

Answer (score 1):

Pick an integer `i` at random with probability `p_i`, the i-th weight. Then sample from the corresponding multidimensional Gaussian distribution. Repeat `p` times.